# "cucumber: command not found" error on command line; "rake cucumber" works fine though

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tags, rake, cucumber

Just updated my cucumber gems on my system and have run into an issue with running my tagged cucumber features. The "cucumber" command no longer works on my command line.

-bash: cucumber: command not found

Initial thought was that my $PATH wasn't set up in my bash_login properly. All seems correct here though, i think:

echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin

The bit to add is that the cucumber rake task runs, but as you know it runs all of the tests for my application. And writing out the specific location for a feature each time i want to run it is a bit of a chore, hence why i am keen to have my cucumber tags working again.

Any thoughts or tips would be hugely appreciated thanks.

Comment: What output do you get from running `which cucumber` in a Terminal?

Comment: These are the gems i have installed: 

cucumber (0.6.4, 0.6.2, 0.2.2)
cucumber-rails (0.3.0, 0.2.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you're getting from bash and the fact that `which cucumber` doesn't give any output indicates that the cucumber executable is not on your path. Check the RubyGems path by running `gem env` and update your operating system path accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was indeed a case of my $PATH wasn't quite set up right. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: `which cucumber` => `/usr/local/bin/cucumber`

but i get the error in jenkins , `cucumber command not found` . Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

try brew install cucumber-ruby
i was facing same issue while installing ruby and running scripts tried this and it worked