# Cucumber: command not found (suddenly broken)

Tags: ruby, bash, rspec, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to self-teach Cucumber and suddenly my terminal is giving me the error

```
-bash: cucumber: command not found
```

I have checked out a couple of 'similar' threads on SA and their either Rails related or aren't particularly helpful. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591576/cucumber-command-not-found-error-on-command-line-rake-cucumber-works-fine)
says about checking your gem env but doesn't give any clue as to what to check it for (at least for a UNIX/Mac noob like me). As the above post suggests typing `which cucumber` gives no output and my `gem env` looks something like this:

```
      - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.3 (2014-09-19 patchlevel 242) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin
     - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/bin
     - /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/username/.rvm/bin
```

if anyone can shed any light on this I'd really appreciate it. Cucumber was working fine not so long ago.

Comment: How about `bundle exec cucumber`?

Comment: Does 'locate bin/cucumber' return anything?

Comment: @infused  `bundle exec cucumber` displays `0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s`

Answer (score 0):

doesn't work

```
сucumber --guess --tags @ie features...
```

works

```
bundle exec cucumber --tags @ie features...
```

The problem is only on IE9.
Is that problem of version ruby, cucumber?
Ruby 2.2.0 Cucumber 1.3.18